# Back Button pressed

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have `TabActivity` which contains 4 Tabs. Each tab have one `FragmentActivity` and 2-3 `Fragments`.

From Fragment, I am going to a `Activity` which is not the part of `Tabs`.
While clicking the Back button from that `Activity`, I want come back to previous `Fragment`,
without destroying that Activity.

I am overriding the `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` method, but problem is that it displays the previous fragment without Tabs. I want Tabs to be displayed...

Comment: Please mark a answer. Its not nice to leave just like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use onBackPressed method in your activity class.

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
       if(you wanto go back){
           super.onBackPressed();
       }else{
           //if you dont want to go back 
           // do what you need hear....
       }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is, instead of using KeyCode Back, you have override the below method in your Activity,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

super.onBackPressed();
```

}
And save the state of your Button using SharedPrefrence, and next time when you enter your Activity get the value from the Sharedpreference and set the enabled state of your button accordingly.

Example,

```
private void SavePreferences(){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("state", button.isEnabled());
}

private void LoadPreferences(){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean  state = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("state", false);
button.setEnabled(state);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
SavePreferences();
super.onBackPressed();
}

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
//just a rough sketch of where you should load the data
LoadPreferences();
}
```